# New to Emberjs Data not displaying on page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

I’m new to ember.js can someone tell me what I’m missing, thank you in advance for your help!

I’ve downloaded the sample bloggr-client here https://github.com/tildeio/bloggr-client. Out of the box it works fine, I've made an update to PostsRoute with a call to jQuery to return a JSON. This work fine, here what it looks like.
[image]

My problem is when I Refresh or go directly to the URL (dev/ember-bloggr/index.html#/posts/18) the data doesn't show.

[image]

I can see the data is returned in firebug.
[image]

**Here is the PostsRoute:**

```
App.PostsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function() {
  return $.getJSON('cf.cfc?method=getData').then(function(d){
  var data = cfQueryNormalize(d)
   return data.map(function(post){
     return post;
   });      
  });
 }
});
```

**Here is my PostRoute:**

```
App.PostRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
 model: function(params) {
  return $.getJSON('cf.cfc?method=getData&id='+params.post_id).then(function(d){
   var data = cfQueryNormalize(d)
    console.log(data);
    return data; 
   });
 }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand why going directly will not work. 
This is how ember does thing, im pretty sure you have post nested within posts.
What happens is that without navigating to your posts ember doesn't know where is the child post the url comes from.

Easy fix is to either use setUpControllers in your route, or use reopenClass on the object you want to return.

I refer wrapping your model with setUpControllers this will make sure you always return a model.
Let me know if it helps.

Comment: Hi Lan, Thanks you for your response. I'm totally new Emberjs and not very familiar with setUpControllers. I'll take a look the EmberJs documentation and see what I can find on this. I'll let you know the out come. Do you have a sampe of what it might look like? thank again!

Comment: setUpController is when you need to manipulate your model. And it occur to me you indeed modifying it via this line var data = cfQueryNormalize(d) in Post that is why i suggest try it out. Here is the documentation http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/setting-up-a-controller/. BTW, you are logging it in Post, did you able to see it on the console via refresh/direct url?

Comment: Yes, I was able to see the data return in the console via refresh/direct url. The last image I attached above is what I get back. Thanks for the link, I'll take I look and see If I can get this resolved.